# Array of values saved in app.locals loses it's array format when used in view. What is happening here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I am creating an array of date values and saving it in an `app.locals` variable as shown below:

```
prepDataList.forEach(function(item){
  var str = item.createdAtDate.toDateString();
  //str = str.substring(4, 10);
  labelsArray.push(str);
  countsArray.push(item.radarCount);
});

app.locals.chart1LabelsArray = labelsArray;
app.locals.chart1CountsArray = countsArray;

console.log("App locals labels array: ", app.locals.chart1LabelsArray);
```

The `console.log()` results are as follows:

```
App locals labels array:  [ 'Thu Mar 26 2015',
  'Fri Mar 27 2015',
  'Sat Mar 28 2015',
  'Sun Mar 29 2015',
  'Mon Mar 30 2015' ]
```

So the `app.locals.chart1LabelsArray` variable seems to be stored correctly as an array.

Now, in my view (or rather in a script tag inside my view), if I call this variable, it doesn't seem to retain it's array format.

1. The type of the object is just `[Object object]`.
2. I can't perform any functions such as `forEach`
3. The result doesn't seem to be a string either, since I could not run a `.split(',');` command on it.

The code:

```
console.log(<%= chart1LabelsArray %>);
```

Results in this error:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Mar'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.  (anonymous function)
```

I tried this with an array of integers as well, and seem to be plagued with the same issue.

When I inspect element in the browser, for the above line, here is what i see:

```
console.log(Thu Mar 26 2015,Fri Mar 27 2015,Sat Mar 28 2015,Sun Mar 29 2015,Mon Mar 30 2015);
```

So it seems that the `app.locals` variable I created in `<%= chart1LabelsArray %>` is getting pulled up, but not as an array. They come up as a continuous set of values, which don't seem to be accessible using any string or collection related functions.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: That's the string representation of an array. A `log` statement expects a string, e.g., it should be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* i didn't notice you were templating into javascript. the below paragraph is less relevant. all you need is to call `JSON.stringify()` when you template in the array.

---

all script has to be inside the lodash tags

```
<%= for(var i=0; i<chart1LabelsArray.length; i++){ %>
<span> label is <%= chart1LabelsArray[i] %></span>
<% } %>
```

PS, for anything more complex than a static list of data, I prefer to pass all data to clientside JS instead of manipulate the DOM in serverside templates. I especially dislike generating different scripts with a template on each request.

```
<body data-labels="<%= JSON.stringify(chart1LabelsArray) %>" ng-app="chartApp">
</body>
<script>
var labels = JSON.parse($('body').data(labels))
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, putting the entire for loop inside the lodash tags makes sense. I will give and update when I get the chance to try this method out.

And yes, I agree about passing data to clientside JS... This application started very small and it served its needs then I guess, but now I definitely need to split concerns and use a model more efficiently. 

Thanks, I appreciate the help!